# Linux software to record .iso from optical drive multi session disk

Tags: linux

Which Linux software can be used to record `.iso` from optical drive multi session disk?

I tried k3b but it said it does not support multi session.
Tried brasero and it did not detect the optical drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with *dd* :

1. **Reading the block size and the volume size:**

[root@testserver ~]# isoinfo -d -i /dev/cdrom | grep -i -E 'block size|volume size'

Logical block size is: 2048

Volume size is: 327867

2. **Running dd with the parameters for block size and volume size:**

[root@testserver ~]# dd if=/dev/cdrom of=test.iso bs= count=

[Link](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Create_an_ISO_Image_from_a_source_CD_or_DVD_under_Linux)

Comment: `dd` did not work, created `.iso` that was empty

Comment: is it audio/video CD or with files?

Comment: just files but with multi session

Comment: Multi session shouldn't affect "dd". Try to mount cd and convert with "Mkisofs" as here - https://vitux.com/how-to-create-an-iso-file-in-ubuntu/